# How can close the tab when open the new tab in same browser?

Tags: javascript

I have opened a website in a browser tab. Now, when I open a new tab from this website, I want to close the first tab in that browser.

Comment: edited tags as php has nothing to do here

Comment: This is difficult. You could do this in JavaScript, but this code would have to have access to the tabs API of the browser and I don't believe (and hope) that JS on websites have these privileges. Of course if you open the new tab *from* the current website then it is easier. But testing whether an other tab already contains the site is difficult.

Comment: This is possible using javascript, i have answered for the same. Please check it..

Answer (score 3):

Use this script

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function click1() {
                window.open("http://127.0.0.1/");
                window.open("http://127.0.0.1/wordpress/?page_id=2");
            }
            function close1() {
                var c="http://127.0.0.1/";
                c.close();
            }
            function newwin (urllink) {
                newwindow = window.open( urllink ,'newwin')
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:newwin('http://www.bbc.co.uk')">bbc</a><br>
        <a href="javascript:newwin('http://www.google.co.uk')">google</a>
        <form>
            <input type="button" value="close me!!" onClick="close1()"/>
            <input type="button" value="Close" onClick="window.newwindow.close()">
        <form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Learn how to format code - just select it and click the editor image with the 010101.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use PHP to close a window but you can use this script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript"> 
    function closeWindow() { 
      window.open('','_parent',''); 
      window.close(); 
    } 
</script>
```

[First Source](http://www.yournewdesigner.com/css-experiments/javascript-window-close-firefox.html)

[Second Similar Demo](http://www.gtalbot.org/BrowserBugsSection/MSIE6Bugs/ClosingWindowsNotOpenedByJS.html)

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newwin (urllink) {
newwindow = window.open( urllink ,'newwin')
}
</script>
```